# Monkey testing filesystem operations within a Windows folder

Tags: windows, gratis, software-testing

I wrote a file synchronization tool, and I want to check whether it crashes when some file/folder operations happen.

Requirements:

- Create/move/rename/delete files and folders of various sizes
- Keep doing that alone for days, at a high pace
- All within a single designated folder (sub-folders are OK)
- Never use more than 1 GB of disk space
- Free
- Bonus if all operations are logged (optional)

It can be a tool designed for this, or any tool that happens to fit these requirements.

Tried:

- The tools at https://github.com/google/file-system-stress-testing/blob/master/docs/monkeytesting.md are all static except CRASHME which gives random input to a program, not random file operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filesystem Monkey](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/filesystem-monkey) does this.

- File/folder creation/deletion/move, all within a folder, various sizes
- Always about 10 files, 10 folders, 300 KB in total
- Open source
- Executes in the current folder by default, you can specify a target folder via command line

[image: Filesystem monkey screencast]

*Disclaimer: Created by me because I could not find anything like this.*